# Inconsistent speed and distance units

Tags: rinsim

When changing the distance and speed unit of the road model from km and km/h to m and m/s (and also adjusting the speed value of our vehicle which is said to use these same units), we get inconsistent results. Using the default units, the vehicle is moving really slow even when giving it a decent speed of 70 km/h. When using m/s and also converting the speed, the vehicle is moving really fast even though the behaviour of the vehicle should be the same.

We are using the same graph of Leuven and methods to construct it as used in the Taxi example. Upon further inspection, we saw that 1000 is used as speed for the taxi's with the default units (km/h and km if we are correct).

Did we miss something, or is there something wrong with the units of the parsed graph?

Comment: I'm not sure what the dimensions/units of the Leuven map are. The example ignores this fact by just using values that seemingly work. You may need to do some tweaking in order to get it right. If you find values that work better than the ones used in the example, let me know!